# How secure is a prompt in a while loop as a password-input?

Tags: javascript, security, prompt, password-protection

```js
var password = "strong_password";
while (k != password) {
    var k = prompt("Enter password");
    if (k != password) {
        alert("Wrong password!");
    }
}
//Subsequent code or html
```

How safe is such a prompt before the website is loaded?
Can the prompt be "ignored" so that the subsequent code is executed without typing something into the prompt?

Comment: Don't handle authorization on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivially insecure, because anyone can simply view the site (or script)'s source code and figure out what they need to put into the `prompt` to bypass it.

If you want to verify that a user has permissions to access something, do the verification on the *server*, not the client, and only send them the data if they pass the verification.

`prompt` is also quite user-unfriendly because of its blocking behavior.

The user will also be able to see the main content if they've disabled Javascript.

Comment: Sure: `view-source:http://wwwu.gym1.at/mhobel11/` I see `var passwort = "";`

Comment: Thank you very much. It did not work when I pressed F12 or made a right-click.

Comment: Not all shortcuts will work while the tab is being blocked, but I at least can still Control-U to open it (or you can just manually type in `view-source...` yourself)

Comment: So now I know what I wanted to know and the question is answered. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

hii your code very good but this is not totally
the right code is written below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var password = "gloryOfSameer";
  while (k != password) {
  var k = prompt("Enter password");
  if(k==password){alert('correct password click ok to continue')}
 else if (k != password) {
    alert("Wrong password!");
    }
}
```